# Touchable opacity doesn't working into item of dynamically updating flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-redux, expo, react-native-flatlist

Link to Snack: https://snack.expo.io/@fakie/flatlist

Touchable opacity in FlatList is not clickable, when I works with state isHidden, when I doesn't update FlatList dynamically it works good.

Comment: not understanding, can you please add some more info?

Comment: The problem is that your `<TextInput>` `onEndEditing()` function prevent the `FlatList` to be clickable, since it comes before the `TouchableOpacity` `onPress()`.

Comment: @Milore , how can I solve this problem?